# How to save group in Skype?

Tags: skype, address-book

I am using Skype 3.5.0.234.

After someone add me in group. I get the Group Chat Window of Skype. But, on my closing that window, how do I go back to it even-if I am member of that group. I can only come back when someone else ping again. Please inform me about how to add this group to my contact.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this group in contacts (see recent chats to see it), but this contact wouldn't be permanent (see [skype.com](http://skype.com) forums for more details about)